# Using db find on something other than primary key

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have searched on the internet for the answer to this question with no luck. I have a model that exists in the database created with entity framework and is accessed via db (an instance of my DBContext class).

```
Function Details(id As Integer) As ViewResult
    Dim bill As Bill = db.Bills.Find(id)
    Return View(bill)
End Function
```

The model for the bill class is defined as:

```
Public Class Bill

    Public Property BillId() As Integer

    Public Property CustomerId() As String

    Public Property BillStatus() As String

End Class
```

Assuming then that in the function mentioned first I was passed the CustomerId rather than the primary key of this model (BillId), how would I use this to create a 'Dim bill As Bill' that included only bills with that customerId.

As in the example above where Bills was filtered with .Find(id) - which only looks at the primary key - I want to be able to use a similar method to .Find() but on a non key field: CustomerId in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you are sure there will always only be one entity matching that CustomerId you can use Single.

VB .NET

```
Dim myBill = db.Bills.Single(Function(x) x.CustomerId = cId);
```

C# .NET

```
var myBill = db.Bills.Single(x => x.CustomerId == cId);
```

Note, this will throw an exception if exactly 1 is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Use .NET's version of filter (Where)

```
 Dim bills = db.Bills.Where(Function(x) x.CustomerId = cId)
```

or

```
  Dim bills = From i in db.Bills
                Where i.CustomerId = cId 
                Select i
```

EDIT: Per Scott's comment call FirstOrDefault() to return only one result. If none exist, null will be returned.
To do that.

```
 Dim bill = (From i in db.Bills
                    Where i.CustomerId = cId 
                    Select i).FirstOrDefault()
 If Not IsDBNull(bill) Then
  /*Do Stuff*/
 End If
```

Comment: Note that this will return a List(of Bill).  You can add a call of .FirstOrDefault() to the end of either to get a single Bill object.  You can read more about LINQ being used in VB.NET here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688088.aspx